# plot a funnel chart with percentage difference using plotly in python

Tags: python, plotly-python

My original dataframe looks similar to the one below:

```
| Sales_entity | country | id |
|--------------|---------|----|
| sales B      | US      | 1  |
| sales C      | US      | 1  |
| sales C      | US      | 15 |
| sales B      | US      | 20 |
| sales D      | US      | 21 |
| sales C      | US      | 2  |
| sales D      | US      | 2  |
| sales D      | US      | 12 |
| sales D      | US      | 50 |
| sales A      | US      | 25 |
| sales A      | Canada  | 3  |
| sales A      | Canada  | 3  |
| sales A      | Canada  | 9  |
| sales A      | Canada  | 11 |
| sales C      | Canada  | 4  |
| sales C      | Canada  | 4  |
| sales B      | Canada  | 5  |
| sales D      | Canada  | 5  |
| sales B      | Canada  | 6  |
| sales B      | Canada  | 6  |
| sales B      | Canada  | 8  |
| sales C      | Canada  | 7  |
| sales A      | Canada  | 14 |
```

Here's the input dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1]*2+[15]+[20]+[21] +[2]*2+[12]+[50]+[25] + [3]*2+[9]+[11] + [4]*2 +[5]*2+[6]*2+[8]*1+[7]+[14], 
                 'Sales Entity' : ['sales B','sales C','sales C','sales B','sales D','sales C','sales D','sales D','sales D',
                                   'sales A','sales A','sales A','sales A','sales A','sales C','sales C','sales B','sales D',
                                  'sales B','sales B','sales B','sales C','sales A'],
                'country' : ['US']*10 + ['Canada']*13})
```

I want to group by country and sales_entity and distinct count the id's. To achieve this, I have used the following code:  `df1= df.groupby(['country','Sales Entity'])['id'].nunique().reset_index(name='count')`
My output from this code looks as the following:

```
| country | sales_entity | id |
|---------|--------------|----|
| Canada  | sales A      | 4  |
| Canada  | sales B      | 3  |
| Canada  | sales C      | 2  |
| Canada  | sales D      | 1  |
| US      | sales A      | 1  |
| US      | sales B      | 2  |
| US      | sales C      | 3  |
| US      | sales D      | 4  |
```

From this output,I want to generate a funnel graph separately for Canada and US such that the funnel displays the value of each sales entity as well as percentage growth/decline. For example, if we look at Canada, the funnel should start with 'sales A' with a value 4 and percentage total as 100%. As we move down the funnel to 'sales B', it should display the value 3 and the percentage change and so on. Similarly, for US, the funnel should start with 'sales D' followed by 'sales C', 'sales B' and 'sales A' displaying their values and percentage change. How can I create a funnel chart using plotly in Python in this case without manually entering the values from my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take reference from here https://plotly.com/python/funnel-charts/.
For Showing % change you can modify the textinfo and choose anything from
`percent initial`, `percent previous`, `percent total`, `value`.[`textinfo Docs`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/funnel/#funnel-textinfo).

If you need some other columns you can add that in data and show in the plot using
[`texttemplate`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/funnel/#funnel-texttemplate)
[Example](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#customize-displayed-text-with-a-text-template)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df= pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1]*2+[15]+[20]+[21] +[2]*2+[12]+[50]+[25] + [3]*2+[9]+[11] + [4]*2 +[5]*2+[6]*2+[8]*1+[7]+[14], 
                 'Sales Entity' : ['sales B','sales C','sales C','sales B','sales D','sales C','sales D','sales D','sales D',
                                   'sales A','sales A','sales A','sales A','sales A','sales C','sales C','sales B','sales D',
                                  'sales B','sales B','sales B','sales C','sales A'],
                'country' : ['US']*10 + ['Canada']*13})

df1= df.groupby(['country','Sales Entity'])['id'].nunique().reset_index(name='count')

USDF = df1[df1['country'] == 'US'].sort_values(['count'], ascending=[False])
CNDF = df1[df1['country'] == 'Canada'].sort_values(['count'], ascending=[False])

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,subplot_titles=("US Funnel","Canada Funnel"))


fig.add_trace(
    go.Funnel(
    y = USDF['Sales Entity'],
    x = USDF['count'],
    textposition = "inside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous",
    marker = {"color": "#1c1847"}
),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Funnel(
    y = CNDF['Sales Entity'],
    x = CNDF['count'],
    textposition = "inside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous",
        marker = {"color": "#ff0000"}
),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,height=600, width=1000)
fig.show()
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I have a question again. The numbers in my original dataset are different than the above sample and they are being displayed as '20.532k' instead of '20532'. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Add `texttemplate = "%{value:,.2d}<br>%{percentPrevious}",` after textinfo line. This updates  the textinfo default formatting. You can read about it on the texttemplate documentation. For formatting found a really intuitive formatting documentation [here](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e)

Comment: The First: define a type of row/col. And make it as str. 
The Second: use `df.apply(lambda x: "" if x in ".k" else x, axis=<DEPENDS ON WHETHER ROW OR COL YOU WORK WITH>)`
The third(opt): convert it into int

Comment: @venky__ The textinfo provides built in percentage and changes. Consider the US funnel - If I want to find percentage change for sales C, I would subtract the value of sales C from sales D and divide it by the value of sales D, that is, ((4-3)/4)*100. Is there a way I can add this information?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out, referring to the official reference.
I made a graph comparing the two countries at the same stage. It was answered by @venky at the same time, but I dared to answer it because the wording is different. Thanks for the opportunity to learn this.
from plotly import graph_objects as go

```
canada_number = df1.loc[df1['country'] == 'Canada','count']
canada_stage = df1.loc[df1['country'] == 'Canada','Sales Entity']

us_number = df1.loc[df1['country'] == 'US','count']
us_stage = df1.loc[df1['country'] == 'US','Sales Entity']

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Canada',
    y = canada_stage,
    x = canada_number,
    textinfo = "value+percent initial"))

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'US',
    orientation = "h",
    y = us_stage,
    x = us_number,
    textposition = "inside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous"))

fig.show()
```

[image]